# Openshift - conecting from a local client

Tags: postgresql, openshift, pgadmin, openshift-client-tools

I did the rhc port-forward -a -appname

the command provide me the correct data but when I tray to connect from the pgadmin (windows client) the error is "problem to connect to the server: password authentification"

I am using the password and user provided from `openshift` setting of my application.

Some idea what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The password you need can be found by SSH'ing into your applcation and then doing

```
env |grep POSTGRES
```

Find the username and password there and use that when you connecct